# Planned SEDE maintenance scheduled for Oct 15, 2021 and Oct 16, 2021 15:00-17:00 UTC (11am-1pm ET)

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, announcements, maintenance

**Update 4**: 2021-10-16 16:33 UTC: Today's window is done. Actual user-visible downtime was negligible.  Thanks for bearing with us!  This round of maintenance is done.

**Update 3**: 2021-10-16 15:00 UTC: Today's window is starting.

**Update 2**: 2021-10-15 15:46 UTC: SEDE is back. Actual downtime was about 30 minutes. We're done. Thank you for your patience.

**Update**: 2021-10-15 15:11 UTC: This is starting now.

---

Due to ongoing planned network upgrades, data.stackexchange.com (a.k.a. SEDE or the Stack Exchange Data Explorer) may be unavailable for up to 2 hours on Friday and Saturday this week.  Likely considerably less.

- Friday, [Oct 15, 15:00](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingdetails.html?year=2021&month=10&day=15&hour=15&min=0&sec=0&p1=224&p2=75&p3=179&p4=136&p5=240)-17:00 UTC (11am-1pm ET)
- Saturday, [Oct 16, 15:00](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingdetails.html?year=2021&month=10&day=16&hour=15&min=0&sec=0&p1=224&p2=75&p3=179&p4=136&p5=240)-17:00 UTC (11am-1pm ET)

We appreciate your patience.

Comment: Is this the last time there's maintanence?

Comment: While we always strive to minimize the maintenance windows that have customer-visible outages or reductions in service, we can not promise that anything we do will be "the last time".  We are in the process of 4 major hardware upgrade projects and this is number 3.  The fourth (and the biggest one) will be announced soon.

Comment: Planned maintenance is good. Sudden unplanned maintenance is not. One precludes the other

Comment: Again not announced on stackstatus twitter/blog?

Comment: @user10354138 it is not an outage that impacts all services in the network. Does this really warrant off-site communication beyond what is offered by featuring this question so those that do use SEDE frequently gets a heads-up? Who on Twitter is interested in knowing SEDE is not available?

Comment: @rene Given at the time I was greeted with basically a blank page with large text saying SE is down for maintenance and redirected me to the stackstatus blog / twitter for more information when it is going to come back up, it is rather annoying there wasn't any information at all.

Comment: @user10354138 yet you found a question that explains what is going on.

Comment: @rene It was more than an hour after the site is back online that I found this and posted my first comment.  Rather useless isn't it?

Comment: @user10354138 maybe the maintenance page should include a link to Meta so everyone landing on that page has three options to get informed, for redundancy.

Comment: @rene Yeah, we forgot to post to twitter/tumblr.  My bad.